# Android Kotlin-Flow: Retrofit Call Fails with No Exception thrown

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to make a GET request to my server from my Android application using Retrofit, OKHttp, and Kotlin Flow w/ MVVM architecture.

For some reason whenever I try to invoke my `GET` request from a try-catch scope the program always enters `catch`, but the value of `Throwable` is always null. It's as if there was a crash but no exception being thrown for me to examine in the logs/debugger.
Filtering logcat for OKHTTP logs I can see that the network request never occurs/reaches the server. It seems to be failing locally, somewhere in my device's app process, before triggering the `catch` block.

Other network calls execute fine in this same project, so something about my specific implementation for this one must be incorrect. What am I missing?

**RemoteDataSource.kt**

```
suspend fun getProductData(skuId: String): Result<ProductLookupResponse>{
    return getResponse(
        request = {
            pickingAPI.lookupProductBySku(
                "Test User", 
                "A place",
                skuId
            )
        },
        defaultErrorMessage = "Error looking up product"
    )
}


private suspend fun <T> getResponse(
    request: suspend () -> Response<T>,
    defaultErrorMessage: String
): Result<T> {
    return try {
        val result = request.invoke() //Always Crashes here for this request
        if (result.isSuccessful) {
            Result.success(result.body())
        } else {
            val networkError = NetworkError(code = result.code(), message = result.message())
            Result.error(message = networkError.message ?: "", error = networkError)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Result.error(defaultErrorMessage, null)
    }
}
```

**Repo.kt**

```
suspend fun getProductData(
    skuId: String
): Flow<Result<ProductLookupResponse>> {
    return flow {
        emit(Result.loading())
        emit(RemoteDataSource.getProductData(skuId))
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

**API.kt**

```
@GET("garments/sku/{skuId}")
fun lookupProductBySku(
    @Header(HEADER_ASSOCIATE_ID) userUniqueId: String,
    @Header(HEADER_LOCATION_ID) dcId: String,
    @Path("skuId") sku: String
): Response<ProductLookupResponse>
```